# Solving problems with formulas (GCD and LCM)

Tags: algorithm, formula, greatest-common-divisor

I'm having a hard time figuring out formulas that are used to solve a given problem more efficiently.

For example, a problem I have encountered was the following:

> *n* children are placed in a circle. Every *k*<sup>th</sup> child is given chocolate until a child that has already been given chocolate is
>   selected again. Determine the *nr* number of children that don't
>   receive chocolate, given *n* and *k*.
>   Ex: *n* = 12, *k* = 9; *nr* will be 8.

This problem can be solved in 2 ways:

- Creating a boolean array and traversing it until a child that hasn't been given chocolate is selected (not really efficient);
- Using the formula: **n - n / GCD(n, k)**;

How would I go about figuring out the 2<sup>nd</sup> way of solving it (the formula)?
Also, where can I practice this specific type of problem, where there is an obvious, slow way of solving it or an efficient one requiring you to figure out a formula?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: What you're asking for is life-long advice on problem analysis.  There is no one path.  It depends on your background, your existing "tool box" or "bag of tricks", and your effective learning styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every problem is different, there is no rule to find a solution. You need to analyse the situation and reason about it. Mathematical training helps a lot.

For this concrete example you can proceed like this: number the children from 0 to n-1. If you start at 0, the children getting chocolate are exactly the ones with a number divisible by GCD(n, k). How many are there: `n / GDC(n, k)` therefore, how many don't get chocolate: `n -n / GDC(n, k)`.